# Error: SVN post-commit hook failed (exit code 16) with no output

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks

I am getting the following error when i do a SVN commit.

> Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 16) with no output.

My post-commit.bat file has following code.

```
svn checkout file:///D:/Repositories/site1/trunk D:\svncheckout\site1
robocopy D:\svncheckout\site1 \\dev-server\site1
```

I am running VisualSVN service as local account on Windows Server 2008 Standard.

But post-commit.bat runs fine from command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is an issue with the `robocopy` command you run in the hook. **Error code 16** indicates either a usage error of the robocopy or an error due to insufficient access privileges on the source or destination directories. I advise you to check the paths involved.

Comment: I have fixed access permission for both the folders involved. Now robocopy is able to copy files. But it does not copy folders. I am getting a new error. Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 2) with no output.

Comment: Some issue with `robocopy` again. See the error codes list at http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html

Try to run the command manually `robocopy D:\svncheckout\site1 \\dev-server\site1` in command-line and see the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bahrep for robocopy exit code. It was not an error. Robocopy returns any of these exit code(0,1,2 or 3) on success. Reference: http://leereid.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/vista-backup-with-robocopy-part-2/